# Grouping using while loop

Tags: php

Example of my record :

```
year  quanitity name
2012     10     john
2012     20     mark
2013     30     david
2013     40     alex
2014     50     stacy

while (!$report->EOF){
        if(is_null($year) || $year <> $report->fields['year']) {
        $year = $report->fields['year'];
        ?>
        <tr><td align="center" colspan="2" >Year : </td><td><?=$year ?></td></tr>
        <?
            }
        ?>    
        <tr><td align="center" colspan="2" >Quantity : </td><td><?=$report->fields['quanitity'] ?></td></tr>
        <?
        $report->MoveNext();                          
        }
```

How to do so the result goes like this

```
year : 2012
name : john quantity : 10
name : mark quantity : 20
Total : 30

year : 2013
name : david quantity : 30
name : alex quantity : 40
Total : 70
```

I want to make a report that will group by year, and get the total for each year

Comment: thanks @john Conde for correcting my post :)

Comment: I highly recommend not doing grouping logic at the same time that you echo out html. First group, second display your html. you have to loop twice, but the computer can loop faster than you can debug code.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over your data, and push each entry to its year's bin:

```
$groupedData = [];

foreach($originalData as $item){

  $groupedData[$item['year']][] = $item;

}
```

Granted that each array has a `year` key.

Comment: is there any other answer?